# Git repos for large project

Tags: git

I have started working on new large project. It contains a lot of Web portals and microservices.

I was thinking how to structure git repo. 
At this moment I have this:

```
Main Folder(one repo)
     Portals(folder)
          Portal 1(folder)
          Portal 2(folder)
     Services(folder)
          Service 1(folder)
          Service 2(folder)
```

And the second option is:

```
    Main Folder(folder)
     Portals(repo)
          Portal 1(folder)
          Portal 2(folder)
     Services(repo)
          Service 1(folder)
          Service 2(folder)
```

And last option I was thinking:

```
 Main Folder(folder)
         Portals(folder)
              Portal 1(repo)
              Portal 2(repo)
         Services(folder)
              Service 1(repo)
              Service 2(repo)
```

What do you think? Is there any standard for doing this?

Comment: There is no such standard. Do these Web Portals & have interdependency or are they related to each other? If yes, then it makes sense to keep entire application in one repository.

Answer (score 2):

There is no objective answer to this question. You should consider though that other than SVN and other earlier version control system Git does strive for small, modular and contained repositories. This makes it easier to branch, which is integral to Git's workflow.

When considering if two parts of a project should be in separate repositories, ask yourself the following questions:

- Can the parts be used separately? (Yes? Then you should use seperate repositories.)
- Will changes to one part almost always require changes to the other part? (No? Then you most likely should use seperate repositories.)
- Will all parts follow the same release schedule? (No? Then you should use seperate repositories.)

Note that the last question in practice is an important one. Even is one part depends on the other part, but releases are not integrated, you should/could split these parts in different repositories. To solve the dependency you would then use [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules); this allows you to lock your dependency repository at a specific version.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular scenario, I'd go with *git submodules*.

```
Main Folder(repo)
     Portals(folder)
          Portal 1(submodule)
          Portal 2(submodule)
     Services(folder)
          Service 1(submodule)
          Service 2(submodule)
```

This way all your sub-projects (Portals/Services) are isolated, yet centralized under one single repo. You easily can remove submodule, and continue working with your main repo, while removed module can still be alive and used for other projects, and can be added later if needed.

Read about *git submodules* here:

- [Official git-submodule documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)
- [Article from GitHub blog](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules)
- [Google know a lot about this](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+submodules)